# Call overloaded, derived function from C++ class on base object does not call the overloaded function

Tags: c++, c++17, overloading

Here is a simplified example ([OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/zKKUrGOxv)):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual int test(Base* parent) = 0;
};

class Test : public Base {
public:
    ~Test() {}
    int test(Base* parent) { return 10; }
    int test(Test* parent) { return 20; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Test* test = new Test();
    Base* base = test;

    cout << test->test(test) << endl; // prints 20
    cout << base->test(test) << endl; // prints 10
    
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect both calls to return `20`, because the argument is of type `Test`, but the second call returns `10`.

I know I could do `dynamic_cast<Test*>(base)->test(test)` and it works again, but in reality I have more classes that are derived from `Base`. Of course I could do sth. like this:

```cpp
auto test1 = dynamic_cast<Test*>(base);
if (test1) {
    test1->test(test);
}

auto test2 = dynamic_cast<Test2*>(base);
if (test2) {
    test2->test(test);
}

...
```

But for any new class derived from `Base` this would need to be adjusted and there are multiple sections in the code that have to do this.

Is there any way, I can keep the `base->test(test)` or sth. similar to get the "right" value based on the argument type?

Comment: Habe you tried putting `virtual` into the declaration of `Test::test`, too? You can add `override` to get better warnings and save you from overloading instead.

Comment: Well, `Base` is not aware that an overload exists that would require a more derived class so it only receives a pointer to the `Base` itself - it cannot know that it would have to attempt to downcast again and call a function it doesn't know exists. To me it sounds like you want to implement a visitor pattern instead

Comment: *because the argument is of type Test* -- The static type is `Base *`, and the best match is `int test(Base *)`.

Comment: This is the weirdest design.  What is the thinking behind having the `int test(Test* parent)` overload at all?

Comment: Can you explain why calling `test` with a parameter of `Base*` on an object of type `Test` should invoke anything other than `Test::test(Base*)` if such a function exists? It's a *perfect* match.

Comment: Thanks, I changed my code to use a modified visitor pattern, got it working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you cast a class, the most specific information is related to the type in the hierarchy you are casting it to.

`Base` [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) doesn't have that overload so there's no way the compiler can know at compile time that another overload exists.

If you think about how the dynamic dispatch is implemented it's rather trivial why your code is not working and I don't see how it could.

You should provide the exact problem you are trying to solve because there could be a different solution to what you're trying to do, stated as it is it looks like an XY problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
base->test(test)
```

`base` is a pointer to `Base`. `Base` has exactly one class method called `test()`. That's the class method that gets called. Since that class method's parameter is a `Base *`, that's what `test` gets converted to. This is how type conversion works in C++.

`base` is pointing to a base class of a derived object, that overrides that virtual method. That overridden method in the derived class, that takes a `Base *`, gets called, because that's the overridden method.

The fact that the pointer, before the conversion, was pointing to `Test *` is immaterial. There is no function in `Base` that takes a `Test *` as a parameter, the only one there takes `Base *` as a parameter, so that's the one that gets called.